# Unexpected linker error: Can't use a function in anonymous namespace within constructor of an exported class?

Tags: c++, c++20

Edit: To be clear, I am asking why the below doesn't work--not how to fix it.  I expect to be able to use a symbol within an anonymous namespace inside the text file in which it is defined, so if there's something wrong with my expectation I'd like to get a more accurate understanding of the issue in which I am running into.

---

I am compiling the following in VS 17.5.1 with /c++latest.

main.cpp

```
import SomeModule;

int main()
{
    auto t = Thing{7u};

    return 0;
}
```

SomeModule.ixx

```
export module SomeModule;

namespace
{
    auto DoSomething(unsigned int x)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

export class Thing
{
private:
    void* _ui;
public:
    explicit Thing(unsigned int x) : 
        _ui{DoSomething(x)}
    {}
    ~Thing() = default;
};
```

Attempting to compile results in the following warning:

```
warning C5046: '`anonymous-namespace'::DoSomething': Symbol involving type with internal linkage not defined
```

And then linking:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__cdecl `anonymous namespace'::DoSomething(unsigned int)" (?DoSomething@?A0x2a23ff30@@YA@I@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl Thing::Thing(unsigned int)" (??0Thing@@QEAA@I@Z::<!SomeModule>)
```

This is confusing me.  I am not referring to `DoSomething` from outside `SomeModule.ixx` so I don't know why this is failing to link within the TU itself.

I don't get any errors when I pull `DoSomething` out of the anonymous namespace, but I want to understand what specific sin I'm committing in this situation.  I read that using an anonymous namespace within a module (or any TU) keeps the stuff inside TU-only, and I know sometimes I want that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put in a bug report with Microsoft and they replied with Not A Bug.

The C++ compiler team responded: "This is ill-formed. The constructor for ‘Thing’ is implicitly inline and calling the internal-linkage function from that inline function is ill-formed because it creates an exposure. To fix this, the anonymous namespace function needs to be outside of the anonymous namespace or the constructor declared outside of the class."

ref: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Function-in-anonymous-namespace-disallow/10307183

I was implicitly inlining my constructor by defining it inside of the class definition.  Once I pulled the constructor definition outside of the class (and the destructor as well), the whole thing worked.

modified SomeModule.ixx

```
export module SomeModule;

namespace
{
    auto DoSomething(unsigned int x)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

export class Thing
{
private:
    void* _ui;
public:
    explicit Thing(unsigned int);
    ~Thing();
};

Thing::Thing(unsigned int x) :
    _ui{ DoSomething(x) }
{}
Thing::~Thing() = default;
```

Moral of the story: I think a good takeaway from this (for me, anyway) is to understand that if the programmer writes a function definition in such a way that they allow the compiler to possibly inline the function, then the symbols in that possibly-inlined function need to be reachable from wherever the function could be called and inlined.  Indeed in this case, if the constructor is inlined at the call site in main.cpp, there would be a call to DoSomething and that wouldn't make sense from the inlined code at main.cpp, since DoSomething is internal to SomeModule.ixx.

---

Edit 3/19/23: I stumbled on a proposal explicitly allowing class methods defined inside the class definition to refer to symbols reachable by internal linkage *within a module*.

https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1779r3.html

The proposal even exemplifies exactly what I am attempting to do.  I have attached that link to my problem report at Microsoft and will update this answer if I hear anything back from them.